# Decrypt Axcrypt encrypted file

Tags: 14.04, encryption

I would like to un-encrypt files that I had previously encrypted with [Axcrypt](https://www.axantum.com/AxCrypt/). There does seem to be a Linux version on their website, but when I run it, I get Windows related errors, and when I run it with Wine I get that it is an invalid .exe format.

I don't really need to use the Axcrypt program, as long as I'm able to decrypt my text files I'm happy. I know Axcrypt uses AES encryption, so has anyone had any success decrypting an Axcrypt file with another AES encryption program?

While I'm waiting for responses, I'll start digging through the source code to see if I can find anything.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I am in the same boat and I've been trying it for a while. $ openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -in myfile-zip.axx -out file.zip enter aes-128-cbc decryption password: bad magic number
I was goin to try Wine, I've heard some have got it to work. You can also try the no-install version AxCrypt2Go.exe

Comment: I looked at the code, there seems to be a header in front of the encrypted data part. I assume your usual AES tool will start decrypting right from the start of the file.

Comment: @RickM indeed the Axcrypt2Go solution worked for me

Comment: AxCrypt2Go works for me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to download Axcrypt2Go from the [Downloads page](http://www.axantum.com/AxCrypt/Downloads.html) and run it in Wine. Looking for portable program is actually a handy general rule for when you need to run any Windows program in Ubuntu.

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly for me in Linux Mint 17! (based on Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: Note: I've recently discovered and started using VeraCrypt. It's awesome, cross-platform, and super easy to use. I now use mostly just Linux and have quit using Axcrypt. Here's a good getting-started VeraCrypt video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C25VWAGl7Tw, and tutorial: https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Beginner%27s%20Tutorial.html. I stumbled back on this answer and question here while trying to unencrypt my Axcrypt stuff before moving it into a VeraCrypt-encrypted container for use mostly on Linux.